# TinyPNG but on Windows to process lots of pictures

Tags: windows, image-processing

I'm working building a site to sell shoes, and I have at least 34K pictures in one of my HDD
I want to upload these pictures to the shopping site, but they need to be compressed first (lossy compression) like on [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/)

The question is:

**Is there a program like that?**

For example feed the software a folder with the pictures and the program does the compression and outputs the files or a folder with the images already processed

A free software would be super useful too.

Comment: So you need a batch converter to PNG, right? In which format(s) are your pictures?

Comment: Sorry if I'm late to answer your comment, The pics are in JPEG format. Since the question was posted i couldn't find a software like that and gave up so i started doing the conversion by myself and the pics that were new were first converted and then uploaded. This process is still in use to this date.

Comment: Posibly this could be helpful: https://sourceforge.net/projects/bulkimageconver/

Comment: i'll let you know if this worked for me, but this is not really a priority right now, maybe in the weekend i'll post an update, Thanks a lot for your suggestion !